# Array of users not passing to the view template

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have a route like this and works fine:

```
    // Dashboard route
    router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
        Note.find({user: req.user.id})
        .then(notes => {
            res.render('index/dashboard', {
                notes: notes
            });
        });
    });
```

on the dashboard.handlebars I can loop the array with:

```
{{#if notes}}
...
    {{#each notes}}

        {{title}}
        {{body}} 

    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

I also have this other route, almost identical, but is not passing the array to the template:

```
    // Admin Route
    router.get('/admin', ensureAdmin, (req, res) => {
        User.find({})
            .then(users => {
                console.log("Users count is: " + users.length)
                console.log(users)
                res.render('index/admin'), {
                    users: users
                };
        });
    });
```

On the console I get both console.log working, I get the number of users and the info. So the Find() is working but the array seems like is not passed to the template.

I suspect it can be because I have a global var:

```
res.locals.user = req.user || null;
```

to keep the info of the logger user. But I changed the variables names on the Find() function and with no luck.

on the template I allways have "No users found" as result

```
{{#if users}}
  <p>There are users</p>
{{else}}
   <p>No users found</p>
{{/if}}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, it was a ")" on bad place...

> 'index/admin')
>   was the cause

Solution is:

```
    // Admin Route
    router.get('/admin', ensureAdmin, (req, res) => {
        User.find({})
            .then(users => {
                console.log("Users count is: " + users.length)
                console.log(users)
                res.render('index/admin', {
                    users: users
            });
    });
});
```